# I got confused, so how should I call the function to get the outputs

Tags: c++, struct

> I'm kinda new to C++ and programming in general. this is for practicing thing that I learn so far.

> Create a structure called `Exam` that includes exam ID (string), name of
> the subject (string), registration fee (double) and the number of
> students registered during a week (7 days) (int array).
>
> • Write a function called `getExamDetails()` which is the data type of
> `Exam` that reads the details of the `Exam` and store them in the variable
> of the Exam structure.
>
> Hint: Use the given function prototype as
>
> `Exam getExamDetails (Exam e);`
>
> • Write a function called `calExamFee()`
> which takes three parameters, registration fee for  the exam, the
> number of students registered during a week (7 days) array and the
> size of the array. Find the total exam registration fee during the
> week and print the total exam  registration to the screen.
>
> • Call the `getExamDetails()` and `calExamFee()` in the main function to
> print the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Exam
{
    string examID,subject;
    double regFee;
    int numStudent[];
};

Exam getExamDetails(Exam details);
void calExamFee(double regFree,int numStudent[],int size);

int main()
{
  
  
}

Exam getExamDetails(Exam details) //reads the details of the Exam and store them
{
    cout<<"Enter Exam ID : ";
    cin>>details.examID;

    cout<<"Enter Subject : ";
    cin>>details.subject;

    cout<<"Enter registration Fee : ";
    cin>>details.regFee;

    for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++) //store number of students registered during a week (7 days)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number of student "<<i+1<<" : "<<endl;
        cin>>details.numStudent[i];
    }
    return details;
}

void calExamFee(double regFree,int numStudent[],int size)
{
    float totalExamFee=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        totalExamFee+=numStudent[i];
    }
    
    totalExamFee=totalExamFee*regFree;
    cout<<"Total registration fee during the week:"<<totalExamFee<<endl;
}
```

Comment: In `Exam getExamDetails(Exam details)` why do you have the details parameter? The signature probably should be `Exam getExamDetails()` and `details` should be a variable local to this function.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing your code

---

##### 1. Unbounded Array

Your struct member `numStudent` does not have its size specified when the struct is defined which in invalid in C++ unlike languages like Java or C#.
You said `numStudent` holds the data for one week, so you can specify a size of `7`:

```
struct Exam
{
    string examID,subject;
    double regFee;
    int numStudent[7];
};
```

##### 2. Smaller datatype in `calExamFee()`

You are accepting the `regFee` as a parameter of type `double`. However, you have declared `totalExamFee` as float which is a smaller/narrower datatype:

```
float totalExamFee = 0;
```

Since you are performing this operation:

```
totalExamFee = totalExamFee*regFree
```

In which you are multiplying a `float` with a `double`, you risk an overflow. Either change the type of `totalExamFee` to be a `double` or change the type of `regFee` to be a `float`.

##### 3. Illegal array access

One of your for loops read `for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++)`. Since the array is of size 7, the maximum valid index is `6`. So change it to `i < 7`.

##### 4. Your `main()` function

Your `getExamDetails()` takes in an `exam`, performs modification on its copy passed as the parameter and then in turn returns another copy of this copy to the caller(`main`). That's a lot of unnecessary copying. One copy happens when you pass it as the parameter and another copy when you return it to main. I've kept it as it is since that is the prototype specified in the question and now we're first focusing on fixing your code.

```
int main()
{
    // Declare the variable
    Exam exam;
    // Call the input function
    exam = getExamDetails(exam);
    // Calculate the exam fee
    calExamFee(exam.regFee, exam.numStudent, 7);
}
```

This will give you the expected results, but we can make the solution better and optimize it a bit.

#### A better solution

---

##### 1. Passing by reference

The purpose of `getExamDetails` is to populate the fields `examID`, `subject`, `regFee` and the elements of `numStudent` and that is its only purpose. We don't need the expensive copying while accepting it as a parameter and then again while returning it. We can prevent the copying by accepting a reference to the same `exam` variable in main to `getExamDetails` rather than copying it. This is called passing be reference and this is how we can achieve it:

```
void getExamDetails1(Exam& exam)
{
    cout<<"Enter Exam ID : ";
    cin>>exam.examID;

    cout<<"Enter Subject : ";
    cin>>exam.subject;

    cout<<"Enter registration Fee : ";
    cin>>exam.regFee;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) //store number of students registered during a week (7 days)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number of student "<<i+1<<" : "<<endl;
        cin>>exam.numStudent[i];
    }
}
```

In `main`:

```
Exam exam;
getExamDetails(exam);
```

Notice the `&` after `Exam`. This tells the function to not copy the variable from `main` while accepting it. Send me a reference to the same variable as in main. Since it accepts a reference rather than a copy, any change in `details` will also reflect in `main`'s `exam` variable. See how the return type is now `void` instead of `Exam`. We don't need to return an `exam` since all the changes have already reflected in `main`'s `exam` variable.

##### 2. One function, one thing

As per single responsibility principle, each function must do exactly one job. Your `calExamFee` does two things. Calculates the exam fee and also prints it. Let it just perform the calculation for you and return the result:

```
double calExamFee(double regFree,int numStudent[],int size)
{
    double totalExamFee = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        totalExamFee += numStudent[i];
    }
    
    totalExamFee = totalExamFee*regFree;
    return totalExamFee;
}
```

In `main`:

```
double totalFee = calExamFee(exam.regFee, exam.numStudent, 7);
cout << "Total registration fee during the week: " << totalFee << endl;
```

Or even:

```
cout << "Total registration fee during the week: " << calExamFee(exam.regFee, exam.numStudent, 7) << endl;
```

The task of printing the result is now delegated to `main`.

Also, it appears that the array size is always `7`, so you don't need to pass it, just hardcode the value:

```
double calExamFee(double regFree,int numStudent[])
```

and use `i < 7` in the loop.